# How to install everything natively without rosetta 2 in M1 macs?

Tags: macos-big-sur, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I have been using M1 macbook for almost half a year and initially, I installed many packages under rosetta 2 and many natively (I assume). I run my terminal under rosetta 2 but whenever I install any package using brew, I do it using `arch -arm64 brew install <pkg-name>`. Now, I have no clue if all this time, I had been installing the packages under rosetta 2 or natively.

Anyways, now I want to install the native versions of all the packages and software since now, most of them are available natively. Please help me to figure out how can I do this. All I want to do is remove everything and then install then natively without rosetta 2.

Some of the things which I want to reinstall are:-

1. Homebrew
2. Mini conda and the python libraries.
3. gcc and g++
4. MySQL
5. Node and npm

Also, in future, if I want to install anything natively then how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Homebrew to install all of the packages, try to uninstall them as you where using brew. Then uninstall the x86 version of Homebrew

And for the native versions, install the new Homebrew with the ARM terminal. And reinstall everything.